# Create a steganographically hidden image with Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to learn how to create a set of images like this: [this](https://github.com/rohieb/zeromutarts-ctf/blob/master/xoxo/xoxo.md). The idea is that there are two seemingly random images, but when you XOR them, you find a secret message. I want to use Python Pillow, probably along with a simple image editor like paint.net. So my question consists of a few parts:

1. How do I generate an image full of random black or white pixels in Pillow.
2. How can I ensure certain areas of my images aren't actually random, but instead identical, ensuring an XOR compare will reveal them.

Comment: XOR is a symmetric process, so encoding is the same as decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of creating those images is really simple. Here is an example how you could do it (not the most efficient):

1. Create two output images of same size
2. Create a template of same size, where 1 (white) means foreground (the hidden message) and 0 (black) means background (purely random).
3. Iterate over both images and the template in one loop:

   - If the template at current position says 0, draw two random numbers (zero or one) and assign them to the current pixel of each output image
   - If the template says 1, draw only one random number and assign it to both pixels

I will not go into detail on how you read your template image, create binary output images and iterate over them using Pillow, as I never tried Pillow. Drawing random numbers however is very simple:

`x = random.randint(0,1)` (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, here's a way to make random binary images:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Make lots of ones and zeros.
data = np.random.randint(2, size=(100,100))

# Cast as 8-bit ints, 0 and 255.
data = data.astype(np.uint8) * 255

# Cast as an image. Pillow guesses mode.
img = Image.fromarray(data)
```

Result (magnified to 300 × 300 pixels):

[image: random pixels]

Answer (score 0):

For future posterity, here's what I did:
First I made a mask image. It was a white background with a red box and black text in the box. Looks like this:[image: Image Mask]

Here's the script I wrote to make the two fuzzy images:

```
from PIL import Image
import random

WHITE = (255, 255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0, 255)

wb = [WHITE,BLACK]

rng = random.SystemRandom()

orig = Image.open('mask.png')

origData = list(orig.getdata())

n1 = Image.new(orig.mode, orig.size)
n2 = Image.new(orig.mode, orig.size)

n1data = []
n2data = []


for x in origData:
    if x == WHITE:
        n1data.append(rng.choice(wb))
        n2data.append(rng.choice(wb))
    elif x == RED:
        y = bool(rng.getrandbits(1))
        if y:
            n1data.append(WHITE)
            n2data.append(BLACK)
        else:
            n1data.append(BLACK)
            n2data.append(WHITE)
    elif x == BLACK:
        y = bool(rng.getrandbits(1))
        if y:
            n1data.append(WHITE)
            n2data.append(WHITE)
        else:
            n1data.append(BLACK)
            n2data.append(BLACK)

n1.putdata(n1data)
n2.putdata(n2data)
n1.save('n1.png')
n2.save('n2.png')
orig.close()
n1.close()
n2.close()
```

Resulted in these:[image: image 1] [image: image 2]

XOR them together and you get this:
[image]